# looping over two arrays in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So i have two map() blocks and 1st block is part of 2nd one, but i dont want 1st map() to affect 2nd one. How to accomplish that?
I'm new in JS and React. Thank you!

```
const Ciklogen = () => {
      links.map((h) => {
        console.log(h.heading, h.text, h.url)
        return (
          <>
            <h3 className='heading'>{h.heading}</h3>
            <p className='kratak-opis'>{h.text}</p>
            <a href={h.url}>
              <button className='read-more'>Read more</button>
            </a>
          </>
        )
      })
    
      return (
        <>
          <Navigation logo={logo} links={links} />
          {cssClass.map((style) => {
            return (
              <div key={style.id} className={`bg-image ${style.name}`}>
                <div className='bg-text'>{ **1st block should be here**} </div>
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </>
      )
    }
    
    export default Ciklogen
```

Comment: What do you mean by _i dont want 1st map() to affect 2nd one_?

Comment: well they seem to multiply. Im getting 30 headings instead of 6.

Comment: It's not clear what the desired outcome should be. You have some styles and some links. If you render all the links for each style of course they will multiply. Please describe the desired outcome. Should the links simply be rendered before the styles? So two flat lists one after another?

Comment: Also where does `Navigation` come from and how does it render the `links` you pass as props? Also mapping over the links without using the resulting array doesn't do anything.

Comment: outcome should be: DIV with h3 and p  should go over DIV with background img set in css. There is 6 bg images as block elements and some text on each one...
1st map sets class with background image and second should loop an array of object with H and P elements. Is it clearer now?

Comment: The code you presented renders a `Navigation` component where you pass an array `links`. I assume, that it renders those links? And then you render another list of `div`s where you apply a `className` to each. What does `{ **1st block should be here**}` mean? Do you want to have the `Navigation` rendered there? But what should then be in the remaining divs? You really need to precisely describe what you want to have because it's not clear from what you described so far.

Comment: Can you maybe describe it in natural language without any technical terms? Something like "I want to render a list of links where each link has a text and an image".

Comment: Navigation component is ok it gets props links yes. In that links.js array i have also text for those H and P elements. { **1st block should be here**} means that 1st map() block should be nested there. 1st map is processing  one array with stylest and 2nd map object with links and text...

Comment: But that makes no sense. You said that you don't want it to be nested because then you would get `n * m` results. Maybe you only want to map over one array and access the value at the same index in the other array? The function passed to `map()` receives the index as the second argument.

Comment: Yes that solves the problem. Instead of looping through 2 different arrays that cause n*m result, use 1 array with all data needed:) at first i didnt see that as a solution! thank you!